# Block not fired

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code and for some reason my block is not fired.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        return 0; 

        HttpRequestHelper *requestHelper = [[HttpRequestHelper alloc] init];

        [requestHelper processRequest:@"www.yahoo.com" callback:^(NSString * response) {

            NSLog(@"%@",response);

        }];


    }

}

@implementation HttpRequestHelper

-(void) processRequest:(NSString *)url callback:(void (^)(NSString *))block
{
    block(url); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you have `return 0;` right at the start of `main()`, so it's going to immediately exit.

Even after that, from its interface, I gather than `HttpRequestHelper` is asynchronous.  It will start processing the request, but won't immediately call the callback.  Rather, it will only call the callback after the request has been processed.  The problem is, you don't give it an opportunity to process the request.  As soon as you've initiated the request, you allow `main` to exit, which terminates the program.

You probably have to run the run loop until the callback is called.

Comment: Ah did not even notice the return at the start. Thanks!